# JQuery returns undefined when I access my image attribute

Tags: jquery

I have an image on my html document and I've put it like this:

```
<img src="picture.jpg:/>
```

I reference it in jquery by:

```
$('img').click( function() {
    alert($(this).attr('width'));
});
```

It catches the event but it returns undefined value. Is there another way on how to extract the width and height?

Comment: What's with the colon in your image tag?

Comment: also , fix that colon , bad html like that may work in newer versions of firefox and chrome , but old browsers get mad at stuff like that

Comment: Oops my bad, its " actually, @j08691 I got your answer and solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @kimbebot - glad to help. Please consider upvoting it or selecting it as the accepted answer.

Comment: The site said: You can accept an answer in 3 minutes. First time it happen, let's wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$('img').click( function() {
    alert($(this).width());
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BHsvm/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
     alert($(this).css('width'));
```

will get the width value , attr is just reading the attribute you set

Answer (score 0):

Missing " on `src` attr.

```
<img src="picture.jpg"/>
```

Use `prop` instead, `attr` always return true. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zVx8s/7/)
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zVx8s/8/) using `prop`

Or without jQuery `alert(this.width);`